# HTTPModule not working on Windows 2003 Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-server-2003

I have an httpmodule code that is running on development server that is running on Windows 2012 server but our Qa is 2003 server, The problem is, the code is not working on Windows 2003 server.

```
<system.web>
 <httpModules>
 <add name="ValidateModule"  type="pro.App_Start.ValidateModule" />
 </httpModules>
</system.web>


 <system.webServer>
 <modules>
       <add name="ValidateModule"  type="pro.App_Start.ValidateModule" />
   </modules>
 </system.webServer>
```

This the code in web config.

Comment: Make sure that both are running in the same type of app pool. Since the httpmodule settings in classic and integrated mode are in different parts of the web.config, they won't work if it doesn't match the right section for the configuration of the app pool.

Comment: Please check the code I added is this fine?